# re-compile from source to include setInterval functionality?

Tags: php

I have a very troubling problem at hand. I am using a web-socket server that runs in PHP. The issue is I need to be able to use a setInterval/setTimeout function similar to JavaScript, but within my php socket server.

I do not have the time or resources to convert my entire project over to nodejs/javascript. It will take forever. I love php so much, that I do not want to make the switch. Everything else works fine and I feel like **it's not worth it** to re-write everything just because I cannot use a similar setInterval function inside php.

Since the php socket server runs through the shell, I can use a setInterval type function using a loop:
http://pastebin.com/nzcvXRph

This code does work as intended, but it seems a bit overboard for resources and I feel like that while loop will suck a lot resources.

Is there anyway I can re-compile PHP from source and include a "while2" loop that only iterates every 500 milliseconds instead of instantly?

Comment: I would imagine this would involve http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php somehow.

Comment: @NiCk I removed my answer, I got tired of people voting it down; I don't think they quite understand the problem (or I'm really *that* unprivy to something magical php does). Are you using a special library with php that causes it to *not* block everyone when it sleeps? I was under the impression from your original question that you're writing a server *in* php. For a websocket server connection to remain in tact with the client, the connection opens and never closes. This means that if you're running a php file outside of a webserver, every single sleep() will block the entire script running.

Comment: (That was also assuming the obvious, that things like shell_exec and passthru were being avoided, as they are giant security risks). I still stand by my original conclusion -- if you're wanting a "service" piece of software, please take the time to at least investigate a language that is meant to respond to such requests. While I enjoy PHP for many, many uses, it was never meant to be used for this. There are numerous tech talks from [the guy who started the whole language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf) expressing this exact sentiment.

Comment: Hey Patrick. It's fine, I respected your answer and it helped me. I am sad you deleted it. But in any event, I am about 80% done re-writing my gameserver to NODEJS! :) I am going to miss my php socket server, but I really need that setInterval and setTimeout functions. The php socket server I can save later for further use. (It was used mainly as a chat server with individual channels, etc). Don't worry Patrick, I still love PHP with all my heart and still use it for the main game website, but just going to have to use javascript/nodejs for the gameserver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. I don't think there is a way to recompile PHP from source.
2. If you want to delay the execution of the loop you could use the `sleep` function, which is used for delaying execution.

For example, I want to print 10 number after every 2 seconds then the code below should do the job.

```
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{
     print($i++);
     sleep(2);
}
```

Check thee PHP docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php).

EDIT

Following up what I mentioned in the replies, if you want the user to have its own instance of the run time, then threads would be an option. There is very limited examples of multi threaded application in PHP, I would recommend to check out some examples in JAVA, it shouldn't he hard to understand. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYN-CBtPNiM) is a good video tutorial.

For PHP

1. [php.net/threads](http://php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php)

Check out the contributor notes, sometimes people write good examples.

Comment: Yeah, the sleep function doesn't work for my project though :(. Since it halts the entire script.  If I have multiple users attacking a monster on the server, there will be bottlenecks for other players. Thank though =].  Hmmm... I really don't want to move to nodejs and re-write everything haha. (Especially just to use setInterval! :()

Comment: I see what you mean. What you could do is to use threads if you want ever user to have its own run time

Comment: would http://pthreads.org/ be a good place to start then? Once I have threads, are you saying the sleep function would be user specific? (So it won't bottleneck other people accessing that script?)

Comment: @NiCkNewman I recommend you to check out the answer posted by Patrick Webster. He is right about threads being bad for real production environments. Check the link about Gearman framework.